# Characteristic of the graph of the function $\frac{1}{c+x^2}$

Tags: functions

[Graph of function $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUxvM.jpg)

The slope of the graph $\frac{1}{c+x^2}$ becomes increasingly negative upto a certain value of $x$ after which it becomes less and less negative and tends to $0$ at $x \rightarrow \infty$. Upon further inspection, this point where it shifts characteristic is found to be at $x= \frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt 3}$

**Why is this so?**

Answer (score 1):

This is the abscissa of the inflection points of this function, because:

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{c+x^2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f''(x)=\frac{2\,\left( -c + 
      3\,x^2 \right) }{{\left(
       c + x^2 \right) }^3}$$

which changes sign at $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{c}{3}}.$

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't very clear in the question. I found the point where it changes characteristic by differentiating it twice and equating it to 0. My question was meant to be: For a given dx, why does the value of $\frac{1}{c+x^2} - \frac{1}{c+(x+dx)^2}$ increase until the value $x= \frac{\sqrt c}{\sqrt 3}$ and then starts to decrease?

Comment: It is the same in fact. Here is why :$$f(x)-f(x+dx)=\frac{1}{c+x^2} - \frac{1}{c+(x+dx)^2}$$ is equal to $-f'(x)dx$ (by definition of the derivative). Consider dx as a constant (if you are not at ease with it, take $\Delta x$ instead and work with approximations). Thus saying that $-f'(x)$ first increases till a certain $x_0$ then decreases means that its derivative is zero at $x=x_0$. But the derivative of $f'(x)$ is $f''(x)$...

Comment: Yes, my question is why does  $ −f′(x)$ increase when x is below $x_0$ and the function $f(x)$ smoothen out at $x=0$ and not continue to behave like how it does beyond $x_0$ and form a pointy tip at $x=0$

Comment: If the function was $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ for $x>=0$, the slope keeps reducing in magnitude. This is because $\frac{1}{1+x} -\frac{1}{1+(|x+dx|)}$ always reduces with increase in x. Let us consider dx to be 0.01. We know that $\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{1.01}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{1.01} - \frac{1}{1.02}$ and that $\frac{1}{1.01} - \frac{1}{1.02}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{1.02} - \frac{1}{1.03}$ and so on. In our function, since we are squaring x, the denominator does not increase in equal steps but increases as 1.0001, 1.0004, 1.0009 and so on, it is understandable that ----contd---

Comment: ---contd---  that $\frac{1}{1} -\frac{1}{1.0001}$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{1.0001} - \frac{1}{1.0004}$ and this term smaller than the next, but why does it stop increasing after a certain value. The difference between denominators continues to grow larger -- It's 0.0001 in first term, then 0.0003, then 0.0005 and so on... This difference will continue to grow, but after a certain value $x_0$, even though this difference continues to grow, the difference between consecutive terms start reducing ( as opposed to the increase till the value $x_0$

Comment: Have you drawn the graphical representation of $f'(x)=\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$ ? Its (maxi/mini) are - in a natural way - in $\pm x_0$. Compare with $g'(x)$ when $g'x):=\dfrac{1}{1+|x|)}$ (which has a "jump" in $x=0$).